# unresolved external symbol (already read similar questions, but no luck)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

I am hacking SumatraPDF source code, and I got a problem. There are 3 files I need to modify:
`SumatraPDF.cpp`, `SumatraPDF.h` and `Search.cpp`. I add `extern HWND testtest;` in `SumatraPDF.h`, and add `HWND testtest = hwndFrame;` inside a function `CreateWindowInfo()` which is defined in `SumatraPDF.cpp`. (Here hwndFrame is the hwnd of some GUI window, which is assigned the value when the GUI window is created.) So far, it could be compiled successfully. Now I need to use `testtest` in a function which is defined in `Search.cpp`, so I write in `Search.cpp`

```
win = FindWindowInfoByHwnd(testtest);
```

But now I get the error

*Search.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "struct HWND__ * testtest" (?testtest@@3PAUHWND__@@A)*

I checked that I have `#include "SumatraPDF.h"` in `Search.cpp`, and I can't figure out what's the problem.

So why the `Search.cpp` can use the global variable `testtest`, which is defined in `SumatraPDF.h`, but `SumatraPDF.cpp` could?

My environment is Visual Studio 2010.

Answer (score 3):

You have to define testtest outside of a function. You can assign it later:

```
HWND testtest;


void CreateWindowInfo()
{
    testtest = hwndFrame;
    …
}
```

What you are doing currently is creating a new variable inside the scope of `CreateWindowInfo` shadowing the global `testtest` which is destroyed afterwards.

Comment: Thank you ! I thought that I have already created a global variable when I wrote `extern HWND testtest;` in `SumatraPDF.h` already.

Comment: No, you don't. Having `extern` in the header is perfectly valid, but this will only tell the compiler, that there is an object named like this somewhere. To actually make this work you will have to define it in one and only one cpp-file, this will reserve the memory for the actual object. Make yourself familiar with the concepts of declaration and definition in C and C++.